# How to get previous scene name in react native router flux

Tags: react-native-router-flux

I need to get a previous scene key in componentWillMount using react-native-router-flux to checkout what screen I come back from and make some action on condition. I looked through a lot but haven`t found an answer. Are there any ways to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its hard to tell, but easier is pass variable when navigating out, like there:

```
Actions.home({from: 'about'})
```

now, `Home` props contain `from` variable, and you can handle this.

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this via 
    `Actions.prevScene`,
which will return the key of the previous scene in your stack.

Comment: It return current scene name

Answer (score 1):

@sftgf's solution should work, but on `react-native-router-flux 4.0.0-beta.28`, it erroneously returns the current scene for me.

This [Gist](https://gist.github.com/omeileo/baacf11e44adcdfa14d392670a62f955) worked and has the added benefit of getting other scenes on the stack:

```
import {Actions} from react-native-reouter-flux

export function getPreviousScene (jumpCount = 1) { // if nothing is passed, it defaults to 1
  const index = Actions.prevState.routes.length - (jumpCount + 1) // because zero-based index

  if (index >= 0) {
    return Actions.prevState.routes[index].routeName
  }

  return 'home'
}
```